# Div / Section width and height?

Tags: html, text, overflow, text-size

I have seen lots of designer don't use width and height to div or section, instead they use padding, is it good practice ? This helps when you zoom-out your webpage and text/content don't get out of div.

**I also have one more question ?** 
I have seen webpages when you zoom out the text never goes out of the div also it gets small. I have issues when I design, Text goes out of div when I zoom out and remains the same size of font. I have tries using overflow, text wrap etc which ever I found the solution nun worked. 
So how you handle it?

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: I always use wrapper and holder which is set to 100% and holder under 1000px say 980 or 960px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using padding to make looks good your content.If u fix the height and width in px and content is large then it goes out . 
   for example .. you have the 1000px screen you set div width 700px when screen resolution width come to 600px the div goes out .. sloution set your width in % like 70% .it helps to adjust width automatically the 70% of 600px.

Comment: Yeah, thats whats I do, holder I always use 980px; not the screen resolution issue. but the text flows out when you zoom out.

Comment: I have added the Picture: 
.serv-sec{
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 440px;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.serv-text p{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #3c3c3c;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 20px 20px 30px 20px;
    text-align: justify;
}


What I have done here to get rid of it: I kept main div height auto which helps on zoom out.

Comment: try after disable min height

Comment: When I disable min-height: div positions differently, as you can see now last Div is slightly gone up :/ ( same happens on normal view)

Comment: Its Local, not yet published.

Comment: ok,just before starting your div add one more div like<div style="clear:both"></div>

Comment: I have tried this , its the same. 
Check these e.g on zoom out : 
Flows out not only from main div but also like the service section I have : https://www.site24x7.com/

Proper site without any issue on zoom out : 
http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/53784.html

Comment: Thank you for your time, Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

[There are some relatively new view port sizes.](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

[Here is a fiddle showing all the things you can do with viewport based sizing.](https://jsfiddle.net/ryfjgo2v/)

```
vw = size the element according to the view port width
vh = size the element according to the view port height
vwmin/vmax = the minimum/maximum width/ the element is allowed to be in the viewport
```

This makes webpages easier to view not only on smartphones but on the desktop/laptop itself.

Comment: No issues in mobile view, handle it through media queries.

Comment: I will try this for sure for my next project and will try experimenting with it. Appreciate your help.